# Hiding/unhiding named ranges: Improve script process time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a script I'm using to automate the hiding/unhiding of groups of rows in Google Sheets.

[image]

Col B contains drop-down menus that allow the user to toggle hiding or unhiding rows according to [named ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175). However, the script is a bit laggy. Here is a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P_Qulj2R2NJPAxmerp3_RDFdegsvA3F8A2aKq6_Dhjk/edit?usp=sharing) where you can see for yourself.

I haven't found a more efficient approach than creating four different arrays in Google Apps Script...but any advice on how to speed up this script would be greatly appreciated!

(NB: The script operates with a "From spreadsheet" and "On edit" trigger.)

```
function hideRows() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");

  //create array of spreadsheet's named ranges
   var namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();
   var named = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
   named.push(namedRanges[i].getName()); 
   }
   var arrName = named.sort();

  //create array of named range values  
   var value = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arrName.length; i++) {
   value.push(ss.getRangeByName(arrName[i]).getValue()); 
   }

  //create array of named range row indexes  
   var index = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arrName.length; i++) {
   index.push(ss.getRangeByName(arrName[i]).getRowIndex()); 
   }

  //create array of named range row numbers  
   var rows = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arrName.length; i++) {
   rows.push(ss.getRangeByName(arrName[i]).getNumRows()); 
   }

    for (var i = 0; i < arrName.length; i++) {
  //If a value in value is equal to "Collapsed" then hide the corresponding named range
      if (value[i] == "Collapsed") {
    sheet.hideRows(index[i+1],rows[i+1]);
      }
  //If a value in value is equal to "Expanded" then show the corresponding named range
  else if (value[i] == "Expanded") {
    sheet.showRows(index[i+1],rows[i+1]);
  }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this.  I rewrote the code, and consolidated three of the loops into one loop.  The code could be consolidated more, depending upon whether you need to further use the data for something else.  For example, you are sorting the range names.  If it's not really needed to have them in order, then the code could be consolidated further.

```
function HideRows() {
  var arrName,i,index,L,named,namedRanges,
      rngByName,rngNumRows,rngRowIndex,rngVal,rows,
      sheet,ss,thisRng,thisRngName,value;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");

  named = [];
  value = [];
  index = [];
  rows = [];

  //create array of spreadsheet's named ranges
  namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();

  L = namedRanges.length;

  for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    named.push(namedRanges[i].getName()); 
  }

  arrName = named.sort();
  Logger.log(arrName);

  //create array of named range values  

  L = named.length;

  for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    thisRngName = arrName[i];
    thisRng = ss.getRangeByName(thisRngName);

    rngVal = thisRng.getValue();
    rngRowIndex = thisRng.getRowIndex();
    rngNumRows = thisRng.getNumRows();

    value.push(rngVal);
    index.push(rngRowIndex);//create array of named range row indexes  
    rows.push(rngNumRows);//create array of named range row numbers

    //If a value in arrValue is equal to "Collapsed" then hide the corresponding named range
    if (rngVal == "Collapsed") {
      sheet.hideRows(index[i+1],rows [i+1]);
    }
    //If a value in arrValue is equal to "Expanded" then show the corresponding named range
    else if (rngVal == "Expanded") {
      sheet.showRows(index[i+1],rows [i+1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sandy. This script throws the error `Cannot call method "getNumRows" of undefined. (line 36, file "Code")` for the `rngByName` variable.

Comment: Change `rngByName` to `thisRng`.  I changed the names and didn't get that third one changed.

Comment: Thank you again! This time, the script throws the error `ReferenceError: "arrIndex" is not defined. (line 48, file "Code")` but I will continue to pore over your code and experiment with it. To answer your implied question, I am sorting the names deliberately, because the order of the names allowed me to more easily match the "drop-down" cells with their corresponding ranges to hide/unhide via `i+1`. That is, I've deliberately named the range for each drop-down cell (e.g. "Alpha") so that it always precedes the named range for its corresponding grouped rows (e.g. "AlphaRange").

Comment: The original code assigned the values from the array `index` to the array `arrIndex` and I had removed that seemingly useless part.  So, replace `arrIndex` with `index`.  I've updated the answer.  I don't know why the original code  assigned the values from the array `index` to the array `arrIndex`.  It didn't seem like that was necessary.

Comment: The latest version throws an error `Cannot find method showRows((class),(class)). (line 48, file "Code")` because (I believe) `index` represents only the first row index in your version. Whereas in my code, `index` represents every named range's row index. Your point on useless assigning of one array to another (e.g. `index` to `arrIndex`), however, is well made and well taken! I will also remove the needless Logger lines, which were only for my testing purposes.

Comment: I often leave in Logger lines, and just comment them out.  Is `hideRows` working?  In any case, if this code helped you, even if it's not the "correct answer" could you upvote it.   Thanks.  Does it run faster?  Is it an improvement?

Comment: Sandy, just upvoted. I'm unable to get your code working (see my previous comment for why I think that is), but you definitely helped point out some superfluous lines, and I've since edited my original question to reflect some of your suggestions. The script doesn't run noticeably faster that I can tell after making those tweaks (e.g. removing `index` to `arrIndex`), but that may just be a reality of the tasks I'm attempting to automate. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I was hoping that getting the range in just one "for" loop instead of 3, would maybe help.  But I guess it doesn't do much.  The line:  `namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();` already gets all the ranges.  But then, your code is getting the ranges *again*, one by one.  So, the code is getting the ranges twice.  I didn't change that, because of the part that gets the ranges in order by name.  There may be an alternative that will work for you without needed to process the ranges in order.